# Canadian with dual passports uk/can can I work?

Tags: visas, uk, canada, work

I am Canadian and I hold a Canadian passport and I am currently in the process of obtaining my UK passport (my mum was born a British citizen). I plan on moving to and working in the UK do I still need a work permit or visa?

Comment: If your mother's transmission of nationality is valid it makes you British then you don't need a work permit, or anything else. Questions about work are beyond our competence here. Please use Expats http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions Close voting as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If you get the passport, you are a British citizen.  This means that you can live and work without restriction in the UK.  British citizens don't need visas or permits for the UK, just as Canadian citizens don't need them for Canada.